# Latex Beamer: Title page subtitle line spacing

Tags: beamer, titles, line-spacing

I am using a beamer template. I want to decrease the line spacing of the subtitle, due to a long subtitle. This is the current line spacing:

[image]

While I am satisfied with the line spacing for the title, the subtitle spacing is too large. I found this code in the `.sty` file, but cannot identify where to adjust the line spacing. I tried forcing the line break with `\\`, but this had no impact on the line spacing.

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vskip0pt plus 1filll
  \hspace{-12mm}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\textwidth,sep=10pt,leftskip=8mm]{title}
    {\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}\\

    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}\\

    {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor}

    {\usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\insertdate}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title page template should finish the paragraphs before switching to other font sizes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vskip0pt plus 1filll
  \hspace{-12mm}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\textwidth,sep=10pt,leftskip=8mm]{title}
    {\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\insertdate\par}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont}% <- second number controls the line spacing

\author{names}
\title{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text }
\subtitle{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @Alschme You're welcome!